# Buying iPhone 4S under another family member's name

Tags: iphone

I would like to buy an iPhone 4S under a different family member's name as their eligibility to purchase the phone is available and furthermore, they're on a different bill.

If I purchase the 4S under my family member's name and activate it under my name... will the "required" text messaging plan, etc. still hold on the purchaser's bill even though the iPhone was not activated under that name?

Note:  This isn't to unlock the phone to use it on a different network -- it would remain on AT&T.

Comment: This isn't an Apple question, this is an AT&T question. You should call them and ask them.

Comment: I'm going to give this an answer. Not only is it related closely to Apple, Apple actually sells the phones and acts as an agent to AT&T so it seems on topic even if AT&T is probably the ultimate arbitrar.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - not only is this allowed, Apple and AT&T have systems in place to effect this purchase. Note - this is only for plans where you are billed together. If you can get on the same plan, just ask them about using a cross upgrade so that you can burn the upgrade eligibility of a different number on your family plan to get a new phone for a line that currently isn't eligible for upgrade pricing.

In your case, where you are not billed together it gets messy. If they don't buy the phone off contract - then the carrier could hold them to pay for the data plan if the contract has that provision. This situation is analagous to them buying a new phone and then selling it on the open market. I haven't heard of AT&T cracking down on this, but you could easily see how they intend the subsidy to generate 2 years of revenue from the buyer.

As you are not eligible for an upgrade, it goes to sense that you haven't yet paid off your last "loan". Have you asked how much it would cost for you to end your contract? Unless you also are on a family plan, you might shop around and then go to AT&T and not threaten to leave, but explain your budget and your options and ask them how long you have to wait or how much you might need to pay to get back to a more budget friendly place for you to upgrade your handset. I've seen times when they'll budge a few months, but keep in mind if you haven't honored your last contract with them, you've got to be reasonable when asking for further accomodations.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you are under the same "Family Plan" as your relative, you can use a cross upgrade and still have the same plan you currently have. At the Apple store the only information the specialist will need is the account holders social security # and if there is a password on the account. This is a very common question Apple employees get, and it's very easy to execute.

Now, if you are not on the same "Family Plan" you will need the account holder there with you to upgrade the device with you.